# How do I access and use data from a class which is stored within the init of another class? (Python)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Hi there and thank you for reading this. At this moment I am working on my assignment for my internship. My assignment is done in Python and I have to use Object-Oriented Programming, but this is not really my strong suit. The problem that I'm facing right now is that I have a few classes with different types of data, but I am unable to access certain data that I need to use. Have a look below for some of the code I've made so far.

```py
    class Field:
        def __init__(self, name, address, field_type, repeat="    ", field_size="[31:0]", data=None):
            if field_type is not "R" and field_type is not "W" and field_type is not "RMW":
                print("Error: field type is invalid")
            else:
                self.name = name
                self.address = address
                self.field_type = field_type
                self.repeat = repeat
                self.field_size = field_size
                self.data = data

        def show(self):
            print("%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s" % (
                self.name, self.field_size, hex(self.address), self.repeat, self.field_type))

    class Regmap:
        def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
            self.name = name
            self.address = address
            self.repeat = repeat


    class TestRegmap1(Regmap):
        def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
            super().__init__(name, address, repeat)
            self.field1 = Field("veld1", 0x00, "RMW", "4s4"),
            self.field2 = Field("veld2", 0x80, "RMW", "64s64"),
            self.field3 = Field("veld3", 0xc0, "RMW"),
            self.field4 = Field("veld4", 0xD0, "W"),
            self.field5 = Field("veld5", 0xE0, "RMW")


    regmap1 = TestRegmap1("regmap1", 0x00)
```

The data inside the class "testregmap1" is an example code that's will be generated. There's nothing I can change with that.

Inside my parent class "regmap" I'm trying to create a function that will print all my different fields that are created in the class "testregmap1". I want the function to still work even if there are more or fewer data inside the "testregmap1" class. I feel like I don't know enough about OOP and Python to figure it out and there's not much I can find about this specific problem.

If you have any information that might help me please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are probably many more approaches to this but i would choose one of these:

1. Create a function that raises a NotImplementedError then implement in new class
2. OR use a list or dictionary for the fields

Method 1:

```py
class Regmap:
    def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.repeat = repeat

    def printFields(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class TestRegmap1(Regmap):
    def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
        super().__init__(name, address, repeat)
        self.field1 = Field("veld1", 0x00, "RMW", "4s4")
        self.field2 = Field("veld2", 0x80, "RMW", "64s64")
        self.field3 = Field("veld3", 0xc0, "RMW")
        self.field4 = Field("veld4", 0xD0, "W")
        self.field5 = Field("veld5", 0xE0, "RMW")

    def printFields(self): # note: same function, different code
        print(
            self.field1,
            self.field2,
            self.field3,
            self.field4,
        )
```

defining a function with the same name in the child class in python overwrites the function.

method 2:

```py
class Regmap:
    def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.fields = []

    def printFields(self):
        for field in self.fields:
            field.show()

class TestRegmap1(Regmap):
    def __init__(self, name, address, repeat=""):
        super().__init__(name, address, repeat)
        self.fields = [
            Field("veld1", 0x00, "RMW", "4s4"),
            Field("veld2", 0x80, "RMW", "64s64"),
            Field("veld3", 0xc0, "RMW"),
            Field("veld4", 0xD0, "W"),
            Field("veld5", 0xE0, "RMW")
        ]


regmap1 = TestRegmap1("regmap1", 0x00)

regmap1.printFields()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Juke, thank you for your reply. I appreciate it. I can't use the second method because the data inside testregmap1 is generated and I cannot change it into a dictionary. With the first method it only allows me to print the location of the objects and not actually the data within each field

Comment: not sure if i understand you correctly, but you mean `<__main__.Field object at 0x7f17936399e8>`. If thats the case you must modify the printFields function to call the Field.show() for the desired fields instead of printing the objects. You could also implement a __str__ for the Fields object so you dont have to call .show https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Comment: You're right but how do I use the data in my object self.field1 because that object has the attributes name, address, type and repeats. But I am unable to use those attributes for anything. What if I just wanted to print out the name of field3, which is "veld3"?

Comment: @DGBMenno You could add a function to the Field class: `def getName(self): return self.name` and repeat for the other variables. Then print(field1.getName()) will print: `veld1`

Comment: @DGBMenno After running myself, Remove the comma's after you define the fields. I don't really understand why but the `Field("veld1", etc), <-` gets translated to a tuple, and you wont be able to access the attributes. Little oversight, oops :)

Comment: It works, thank you so much. I didn't realize it's a tuple. I really appreciate your help.